# Returning value from foreach in subroutines

Tags: perl, function, return-value

Consider following simple example:

```perl
#!perl -w
use strict;

sub max {
    my ($a, $b) = @_;
    if ($a > $b) { $a }
    else { $b }
}

sub total {
    my $sum = 0;
    foreach (@_) {
        $sum += $_;
    }
    # $sum; # commented intentionally
}

print max(1, 5) . "\n"; # returns 5
print total(qw{ 1 3 5 7 9 }) . "\n";
```

According to [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920018452?green=c142e8ee-fefc-4f4d-80d1-fb6d1f20e787&cmp=af-mybuy-0636920018452.IP) (page 66):

> “The last evaluated expression” really means the **last expression** that
>   Perl evaluates, rather than the last statement in the subroutine.

Can someone explain me why `total` doesn't return `25` directly from `foreach` (just like `if`) ? I added additional `$sum` as:

```
foreach (@_) {
    $sum += $_;
    $sum;
}
```

and I have such warning message:

> Useless use of private variable in void context at ...

However explicit use of `return` works as expected:

```
foreach (@_) {
    return $sum += $_; # returns 1
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html):

> If no return is found and if the last statement is an expression, its
>   value is returned. If the last statement is a loop control structure
>   like a foreach or a while, the returned value is unspecified.

Comment: @Grzegorz BTW, [PBP](http://refcards.com/docs/vromansj/perl-best-practices/refguide.pdf) recommends to always return via an explicit `return`.

Comment: I thought that is more "Perlish" to omit optional `return`, but I agree with that tip, because explicit style is generally more conspicuous for programmer. Thanks for PBP.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski, No, I don't think there's a strong trend to omit `return`. Some do, some don't. I personally don't omit `return` unless it's a single line sub. A `return;` (no operand) is virtually never used at the end of of a sub that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Grzegorz Szpetkowski, There was talk of having `for` return something sensible, like a list of the last value evaluated by each pass of the body, but nothing came of it.